# wix Managed Bootstrapper: Engine.EvaluateCondition() requires separate thread?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

In my Managed Bootstrapper, I tried to call Engine.EvaluateCondition("MY_PROG_FOUND"); in Run() method. But it never evaluates and said something like: "This requires a running thread." and it never evaluates.

I'm trying to evaluate Bundle conditions in my managed bootstrapper but still no luck.

MY_PROG_FOUND is defined in Bundle code:

```
<util:RegistrySearch  Id="PETRELINSTALLLOCATION" 
        Variable="MY_PROG_FOUND"                      
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"       
        Value="$(var.my_prog_env_var)"
        Result="exists"
    />

    <bal:Condition Message="[WixBundleName] required the installation of My Program.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR (MY_PROG_FOUND)]]>
    </bal:Condition>
```

How can I use Engine.EvaluateCondition() in managed bootstrapper? Does this requires to be called in a specific event, like DetectBegin()??

Any help would be really appreciated...
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later I figured out that the separate thread is active during event calls. So I tried it during **DetectComplete** event and it worked. 
 
 But before that, I had to parse **BootstrapperApplicationData.xml** file to get **WixBalCondition** elements and get the collection into an array e.g. BalConditions[].

Here is my code snippet:

```
void BootstrapperApplication_DetectComplete(object sender, DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
            {
                string balCondtionMessages = string.Empty;
                bool balConditionStatus = true;
                foreach (var balCondition in bootAppData.BundleData.BalConditions)
                {
                    if (!model.BootstrapperApplication.Engine.EvaluateCondition(balCondition.Condition))
                    {
                        balConditionStatus = false;
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(balCondtionMessages))
                        {
                            balCondtionMessages = balCondtionMessages + '\n' + "- " + balCondition.Message;
                        }
                        else
                            balCondtionMessages = "- " + balCondition.Message;
                    }


                }

                if (!balConditionStatus) 
                {
                 SetbalConditionMsg(balCondtionMessages);
                }    
        }
```

This makes us parse for all conditions in our Bundle.wxs code, evaluate them and display the related message in our Custom Bootstrapper UI.